# Access Runtime 2016 update

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, office365, ms-access-2016

I use office 365 and develop access apps for others.  They use Access runtime 2016.  I am now having problems when I create an .accde file to share with them that they get an error 'unrecognized database format' error.  It states it may be created on a newer version of access.  Both are using Access 2016, but I think my office 365 version # is newer than the access runtime version #.  I can't figure out how to update their access runtime (they have automatic updates turned off, as well as internet access).  I need an offline way to download these updates and 'update' the runtime so it will be compatible with my versions.

My temporary workaround is I have another computer with standalone Access 2016 installed.  I don't allow it to update automatically and so it is an older version number and thus allows me to create .accde files which work for them... but it is super annoying having to triple transfer the files.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the `Large Number` (BigInt) data type on any of your fields, by chance? That type has recently been added, and is only supported on the most recent versions of Access 2016. I believe an update for the runtime version is not yet available.

Comment: Nope - no bigint data types.  This is really an access 2007 database that was updated for access web control in 2016.  Worked great for a few months, but the last month or so has stopped working on all computers that have updates turned off.  I can't convince them to turn the updates on, so I either need to be able to download offline updates for runtime, or somehow un-update my office 365 to an older version so it will start working again.

Comment: Note that you can download the non-click to run version of Office on an Office 365 subscription as outlined [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Office-2016-offline-installer-f0a85fe7-118f-41cb-a791-d59cef96ad1c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).  This gives you some more control over the updates (aside from the usual advantages, such as being able to use COM and ODBC outside of Office programs without hassle)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did not know about that.  I will try it out and let you know how it works for me.

Comment: Either upgrade "their" pc or uninstall "office" updates for your office 365 and bring it to the same xx.x.xxxx.xxxx version. Usually the office service pack updates are the culprits.

Comment: That is what I am wondering how to do - how to update their office... however, it is not online, and not a full version, just access runtime, and I can't seem to find the updates necessary to get it up to the correct version.